# Finding a greedy optimal solution

Tags: algorithm, greedy

Is there a greedy algorithm to solve this problem:
I have n television, each television has a height and a width.
r buyers come at the same time to my shop. Each one wants a television with a known minimum height and a minimum width.

What is the maximum number of commands I can fulfill?

Comment: And each television has price? And you want to maximize revenue? Otherwise you can just sell to any customer tv with minimum requirements.

Comment: @ipoteka The problem is that there is no ordering on the TVs because the aspect ratios are not fixed. Consider you have a 5x3 and a 3x4 TV. Customer 1 wants a TV with minWidth=3 and minHeight=0. You would probably give the 3x4 TV to him. But if then customer 2 wants a minWidth=0 and minHeight=4 TV, you're stuck. If you had given the other TV to customer 1, you could have fulfilled both commands. And that's exactly the reason why I doubt that there is a greedy algorithm for this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is of maximum graph matching. You create a graph with left side nodes representing customers and right side nodes representing televisions. A edge between left side node and right side node represent that customer can buy television(meaning television passes the minimum height- width requirement of customer). Now you have to find maximum matching in the graph.